# is it possible to play pre-roll, post-roll ads using html5?

Tags: html5-video, ads

I'm doing it using Flash, however I also need same approach using HTML5. If it is not possible, is there any work around for this issue?

This is not what i want but I tried playing real video when ad video ends using onend event listener, but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nextVideo = "http://....../real_video.mp4";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onend = function(){
   videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;   
}
</script>

<video id="videoPlayer" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://.../ad_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I thought that the mistake is that

```
videoPlayer.onend
```

I changed it to

```
videoPlayer.onended
```

But that doesn't work either.

Finally I add eventlistener as below and it worked.

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="http://..../realVideo.mp4" autoplay autobuffer controls />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var nextVideo = "http://../nextVideo.mp4";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        }, false);

</script>
```