# force autoplay after video pre-roll with <source> tags

Tags: iphone, ipad, html5-video

I'm working on some video player ad / playlist logic.  When I was using just the src attribute, I was able to get the video to automatically play after the ad by listening for the video end event and changing the src attribute while in that callstack.  There's a question on that here: [is it possible to play pre-roll, post-roll ads using html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416229/is-it-possible-to-play-pre-roll-post-roll-ads-using-html5) illustrating this technique.

Now I'm using the  tags to list multiple sources for the main video and I can't seem to get the autoplay to work.  Does anyone have experience with this and are there any techiniques to make this work?